# Retrieve the database rights from php?

Tags: php, mysql, rights

I'm thinking about some database management system, and my question is simple :

Is there a simple and reliable way to retrieve the access rights (write, readonly etc.), by a PHP code?

I haven't wrote any code yet, as this is just in my mind for now, that will just help me to structure some tables.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-privileges.html

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html

Comment: Thanks @vascowhite, I just need some string parsing at this give a result like `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ...` but I can deal with it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All database permissions are stored in a default mysql database: `information_schema`. Simply create a MySQL user who has permissions to view entries in this table, and use this user's login credentials when connecting from a PHP script. You can the retrieve permissions from the various permissions tables (which include DB level, table level, and column level permissions) to report back user rights. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM`information_schema`.`user_privileges` WHERE`grantee` LIKE"'user'%";
```

Once you've run this query you can format the results however you'd like in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I will deal with this table. I never really had a deep look a it.